# WC_Cart::get_cart_url is deprecated since version 2.5

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am getting the error in my debug log -

```
[22-Mar-2019 12:25:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  WC_Cart::get_cart_url is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 2.5! Use wc_get_cart_url instead. in /home/176860.cloudwaysapps.com/tzshvjkjbz/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4329
```

What could be causing this error? The line of code specified aove is inside a comment which says:

```
 * A return value of `1` means the file path contains directory traversal.
```

So I have no idea where to go from this error message. I've also searched my entire directory for `WC_Cart::get_cart_url` and it is not being used anywhere.

Comment: It must be somewhere, otherwise you wouldn't be getting that PHP notice. Try switching to a different theme and see if the issue persists. If it does then it's somewhere in your theme, otherwise try disabling all of your plugins (except for WooCommerce) and check again.

Comment: Search for get_cart_url()